# Need help putting data results into a drop down menu using linq razor mvc3 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my Controller code:

```
public ActionResult CreateMatch()
{
    var db = new MatchGamingEntities();

    ViewBag.MatchTypes = db.MatchTypes.OrderBy(m => m.MatchTypeName).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Here is my View:

```
    @model MatchGaming.Models.MatchModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateMatch";
}

<h2>CreateMatch</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MatchModel</legend>
        ...    
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchTypeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor("MatchTypeId", 
            new SelectList(ViewBag.MatchTypes as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
                "MatchTypeId", "MatchTypeName"));
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wager)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wager)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wager)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is my MatchModel:

```
public class MatchModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Match Name")]
    public string MatchName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Match Description")]
    public string MatchDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Match Type")]
    public int MatchTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Wager Amount")]
    public string Wager { get; set; }

    public virtual MatchType MatchType { get; set; }
    public string MatchTypeName { get; set; }

}
```

All I am trying to do is get the results in my controller from my table "MatchTypes"  I want to take those results and put it into the dropdown list.  The two tables I am dealing here with are MatchTypes and Matches, they both share the MatchTypeId column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to DropDownList instead of DropDownListFor.  You're passing MatchTypes in the ViewBag.

If you want to use DisplayModelFor add MatchTypes to your ViewModel as a SelectList.

example:

in view model:

```
public SelectList BuildingTypes { get; set; }
```

in controller:

```
BuildingTypes = new SelectList(_db.BuildingTypes.ToList(), "Id", "Name")
```

in view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BuildingTypeId, Model.BuildingTypes)
```